# spatial_softmax layer in tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, softmax

Tensorflow 1.X used to have a layer `tensorflow.contrib.layers.spatial_softmax`. The layer basically does a softmax over each channel and returns the coordinates of the maximum point.

However, this functionality seems to be missing in TF 2.0. Is this just not ported yet, or do I miss something?
Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6271#issuecomment-266893850) comment, apparently spatial softmax can be easily implemented.